# Fix button at bottom when entering viewport

Tags: jquery, html, css, position, sticky

Hy there.
I would like to fix a button at bottom when entering viewport.
I try get it fixed.
I'm wondering what is your proposition to this problem.
I tried [Sticky-Kit | jQuery plugin for sticky elements](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/) or [Sticky Plugin](http://stickyjs.com) but the fix element always stay at top.

Comment: What code have you tried before, and what's been the result? Are you having any specific errors? We need a bit more info.

Comment: Without context, you could try `.sticky-button {position:fixed;bottom:0;left:50%;}`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on what you've given us - this is what I assume you want and could do. I'm starting from scratch so don't expect an exact implementation.

First off, here is a JsFiddle for you to follow along with: https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/y34fdrvg/1/

Besides all the extra code on the Fiddle (for styling and functionality), you're primarily concerned with the jQuery.

First, you will set your variables for this, the variables are the navContainer and the unordered list. You will also need to set a variable that is the 'browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "menu" link is shown':

```
// browser window scroll (in pixels) after which the "menu" link is shown
var offset = 300;

var navigationContainer = $('#cd-nav'),
    mainNavigation = navigationContainer.find('#cd-main-nav ul');

//hide or show the "menu" link
checkMenu();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkMenu();
});
```

The checkMenu function is where the magic happens though:

```
function checkMenu() {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > offset && !navigationContainer.hasClass('is-fixed')) {
        navigationContainer.addClass('is-fixed').find('.cd-nav-trigger').one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(){
            mainNavigation.addClass('has-transitions');
        });
    } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= offset) {
        //check if the menu is open when scrolling up
        if( mainNavigation.hasClass('is-visible')  && !$('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions') ) {
            //close the menu with animation
            mainNavigation.addClass('is-hidden').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function(){
                //wait for the menu to be closed and do the rest
                mainNavigation.removeClass('is-visible is-hidden has-transitions');
                navigationContainer.removeClass('is-fixed');
                $('.cd-nav-trigger').removeClass('menu-is-open');
            });
        //check if the menu is open when scrolling up - fallback if transitions are not supported
        } else if( mainNavigation.hasClass('is-visible')  && $('html').hasClass('no-csstransitions') ) {
                mainNavigation.removeClass('is-visible has-transitions');
                navigationContainer.removeClass('is-fixed');
                $('.cd-nav-trigger').removeClass('menu-is-open');
        //scrolling up with menu closed
        } else {
            navigationContainer.removeClass('is-fixed');
            mainNavigation.removeClass('has-transitions');
        }
    } 
}
```

I won't go into much detail about the function because I believe it is fairly straightforward. The only thing you will have to really look into is which styles are being applied when the offset is reached and vice versa.

I believe this is the type of solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it with [inview](https://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin).
See it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fiddlepork/y27nek7a/)

```
$(function () {
  $('p.inviewOne').one('inview', function (event, visible) {
      if (visible) {
          $(this).text('Single bound found - I won\'t change again.').addClass('fixed');
      }
  });

  $('p.inview').bind('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible) {
      $(this).text('Yay! You can see me!');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Hidden again. Muhahah!');
    }
  });
});
```